# Unable to get updated props in setInterval React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am unable to get the updated prop in setInterval inside Component1, it gives me the old value

following is the code I am using:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Component1 counter={counter} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Component1 = ({ counter }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(counter);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    };
  }, []);
  return <h1>Component1 count: {counter}</h1>;
};
```

In this code inside Component1, the counter's value is updated after every second on the browser, but on the console.log inside setInterval, I am always getting the initial value not the updated one.

I also get a solution which looks like this

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Component1 counter={counter} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Component1 = ({ counter }) => {
  const counterRef = useRef(null);
  counterRef.current = counter;
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(counterRef.current);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    };
  }, []);
  return <h1>Component1 count: {counter}</h1>;
};
```

But in this solution, I have to use extra memory space as I am creating a ref and assigning value to it.

**Is there any better solution there to get updated value inside setInterval to this the correct way to do it.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one in scenario, where you face closure behavior of JavaScript,

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('count is', counter);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [counter]);
```

But in your scenario this will be more suitable in Component1,

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(counter);
  }, [counter]);
```